# Got “Unknown custom element” while rendering using vue with typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

The current approach is this:
First put a 'modules.d.ts' file under 'src' folder to define vue module:

```
// modules.d.ts
declare module "*.vue" {
    import Vue from "vue";
    export default Vue;
}
```

And write a `index.ts` file under my `components` folder for importing all components and use them anywhere:

```
// components/index.ts
import App from './app/app.vue';
import Pager from './pager/pager.vue';

export { App, Pager };
```

Finally register sub components with `@Component` from `vue-class-component` at where it's been used:

```
// components/app/app.ts
import { Pager } from '@/components';
@Component({
    components: {
        'pager': Pager
    }
})
export default class App extends Vue {

}
```

But sub components haven't been rendered and get this error in console:

`[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <pager> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

And if I import vue file directly it works just fine:

```
// components/app/app.ts
//import { Pager } from '@/components';
import Pager from '@/components/pager/pager.vue';
@Component({
    components: {
        'pager': Pager
    }
})
export default class App extends Vue {

}
```

Could anyone please tell me where's the wrong, and what's the correct way?

Folder structure:

```
.
`-- src
    |-- components
    |   |-- app
    |   |   |-- app.css
    |   |   |-- app.ts
    |   |   `-- app.vue
    |   |-- index.ts
    |   `-- pager
    |       |-- pager.css
    |       |-- pager.ts
    |       `-- pager.vue
    `-- modules.d.ts
```

Comment: I think it’s just a typo! Use `Components: { Pager }` (If I remember correctly)

Comment: @Kokodoko Do you mean: `@Component({ components: { Pager }})`? I tried but still didn't work. Not familiar with this editor so edit my comment several times, sorry if it bothers you.

Comment: Yes, that's how I use it. Also, if you export a default class you can use `import Pager from ...`, if you don't use the `default` keyword, you have to import using `import {Pager} from ...`. For example `export default class Pager extends Vue`

Comment: @Kokodoko What I want to do is to import all components in one single file (components/index.ts) and export them again so I can import components from this file rather than import its .vue file. And I did use `default` keyword in my .ts file but I think there's nothing about it.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. But if you want to register components to be able to use them anywhere, you might consider registering them globally instead of locally. `Vue.component('pager', Pager)`

Comment: @Kokodoko I've tried but still don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change how component is registered and it will work.
Change

```
@Component({
    components: {
        'pager': Pager
    }
})
```

into

```
@Component({
    components: {
        'pager': () => Promise.resolve(Pager)
    }
})
```

Comment: @aviau Not sure, guess it's related to async components or sth else.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one, moving index.ts to upper dir(under /src) should work.

Comment: Forgot to update this. Just change how the component is registered and it will be ok. I'll answer this later.